# Polars: AWS S3 conection pooling

Tags: python, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, python-polars

I want to use Polars to read from Parquet files stored on S3. I'm running my code in AWS Lambda.

When using boto3 I would make a client in the global scope in order that the connection is reused for each invocation (e.g, a client is made for each Lambda cold start, but not for each invocation):

```py
client - boto3.client("s3")

def handler(event, context):
    # Use the client here, ensuring the connection already exist
```

The Polars documentation says that Polars can connect to S3 for me by looking at the location of the file I'm reading:

```py
df = pl.read_parquet("s3://path/to/file.parquet")
```

However, if I put this inside the handler, I assume the connection is re-created for each Lambda invocation. I really want to be able to pass a connection into `read_parquet` (or `scan_parquet`, or other IO methods) like:

```py
df = pl.read_parquet("s3://path/to/file.parquet", connection_options={"aws": {"client": client}})
```

My reading of the docs is that the `client` config is simply about *how* it connects, not a client object.

If I'm wrong and I can pass a client, what sort of object should it be? Am I wrong in assuming that a connection pool is useful here, or is the underlying API doing this for me, in some way?

Comment: I've not used this part of Polars but the docs for `storage_options` link to the `object_store` crate for aws: https://docs.rs/object_store/latest/object_store/aws/struct.AmazonS3Builder.html - So it looks like `object_store` is the client and it's not something that you can pass from Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made an [issue for this](https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/issues/14572) and the Polars maintainers [made a change](https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/pull/14598) that improves the cache performance.

However, as per my comment on the issue, using `boto3` to download the files is still faster than using Polars to read from S3.

I don't know exactly what part of the `object_store` / Polars stack is slower than boto3, but at the time of writing I'm using boto3 in my application.